# Problems with installing nvidia grid driver

Tags: google-compute-engine, nvidia

I want to use gpu acceleration for my android emulator in a compute engine instance.
I added tesla t4 gpu and now trying to install the gpu grid driver according to here.
I use ubuntu 20. please advise
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-grid-drivers

I get an error:

```
in file included from /tmp/selfgz11598/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.92-grid/kernel/nvidia/nv-rsync.c:24:
/tmp/selfgz11598/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.92-grid/kernel/common/inc/nv-linux.h:1775:6: error: "NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTA
NCES" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror=undef]
 1775 | #if (NV_BUILD_MODULE_INSTANCES != 0)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

c1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /tmp/selfgz11598/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.92-grid/kernel/nvidia/nv_uvm_int
erface.o] Error 1
/tmp/selfgz11598/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.92-grid/kernel/nvidia/nvlink_linux.c: In function ‘nvlink_sleep’:
/tmp/selfgz11598/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.92-grid/kernel/nvidia/nvlink_linux.c:570:5: error: implicit declaration of
 function ‘do_gettimeofday’; did you mean ‘efi_gettimeofday’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  570 |     do_gettimeofday(&tm_aux);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |     efi_gettimeofday
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /tmp/selfgz11598/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.92-grid/kernel/nvidia/nvlink_lin
ux.o] Error 1
make[2]: Target '__build' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1731: /tmp/selfgz11598/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.92-grid/kernel] Error 2
make[1]: Target 'modules' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-1021-gcp'
make: *** [Makefile:79: modules] Error 2
ERROR: The nvidia kernel module was not created.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find sug
gestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.co
m.
(END)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-grid-drivers) you are using to install NVIDIA GRID® drivers for virtual workstations, only contains examples of the commands needed to install the GRID drivers.

The example contained in that guide, is for installing the NVIDIA 410.92  driver, this driver is for GRID7.1, but I recommend  to use the latest version of GRID, you can consult the following [table](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/grid-drivers-table#expandable-1)  to see the drivers available.

I’ve reproduced this scenario on my own project and I was able to install GRID11.0, using the NVIDIA 450.51.05 driver.
I’m using an instance with the following characteristics:

- Machine type: n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory)
- GPUs: 1 x NVIDIA Tesla T4
- OS ubuntu-minimal-2004-focal-v20200702

Keep in mind that you need to have the option Enable Virtual Workstation (NVIDIA GRID) enabled at the creation moment to avoid issues.

I used the following commands for this installation:

```
user@instance-1:~$ curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/nvidia-drivers-us-public/GRID/GRID11.0/NVIDIA-Lin
ux-x86_64-450.51.05-grid.run
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  139M  100  139M    0     0  72.2M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 72.1M
```

```
user@instance-1:~$ sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.51.05-grid.run
Verifying archive integrity... OK
Uncompressing NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 450.51.05.....................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
........................................................................
```

```
user@instance-1:~$ nvidia-smi
Mon Jul 27 21:11:17 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.05    Driver Version: 450.51.05    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   73C    P8    21W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In my case I needed to install some dependencies like the gcc compiler, and I only used the command

`$ sudo apt install build-essential`

I hope this information is useful for you.